# WCF ServiceContract's method returning Task<T> and timeout

Tags: wcf

I'm new to WCF. I'm making a service in which I need to compute a lengthy operation.
Since the method is lengthy I thought I could make the operation async by returning a Task.
But it does not work. I'm still getting a Timeout exception.
Sample code (not my actual code) demonstrating my problem below:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculator
{
   [OperationContract] 
   Task<double> ComputePiAsync(ulong numDecimals);
}

internal class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public async Task<double> ComputePiAsync(ulong numDecimals)
    {
        return await SomeVeryVeryLongWayOfComputingPi(numDecimals);
    }
}

// server
using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Calculator), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "Calculator");
    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Service is running. Press <ENTER> to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    host.Close();
}

// client
var factory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/Calculator"));
var calculator = factory.CreateChannel();
await calculator.ComputePiAsync(numDecimals); // <--- this call takes longer than 1 minute and I'm getting a timeout here.
```

So what should I do in order to call a lengthy operation on my service and wait for the result asynchronously ?
Increase timeout ?
If I increase the operation timeout, what's the point of having the method return a Task ?

Answer (score 16):

> Since the method is lengthy I thought I could make the operation async

Hold on, slow down - you are mixing up *asynchrony* with *network operation timeout*.

Lets consider *asynchrony* first:

**1. Using `async/await` to *asynchronously* call a WCF service from client**

`async/await` on client side helps us to write asynchronous program so that the application remains responsive - in case of say `WPF/WinForm` we don't want to freeze the UI by calling a WCF service synchronously on the UI thread. Instead we can call it *asynchronously* using `async/await`. The magic here is that this is complete client side functionality - meaning the  service need not be asynchronous or need not return a `Task` - all you have to to is while creating the `service reference(proxy)` you have to tell `Visual Studio` to generate `Task` based async operations - and you can then use `async/await` on your client.

**2. Then What is the need for `async/await` on service side?**

The service itself may perform some `I/O` like query some data source or in-turn call another service. By using `async/await` on service side - the service can perform these operations asynchronously - *without blocking any service threads*. Which means service has more free threads to serve new clients - hence service scales much better.

**Now, above two should not be confused with *long running* service operation**

When your service takes long to get results, you are dealing with *network timeouts*. You cannot and should not try to keep a network connection indefinitely open without any activity. `WCF` helps you with this by configuring various timeouts. If your service method takes long to respond, you will have to increase those timeouts. You can consider using `WCF callback contracts` if you want to report progress back to the client. If that does not suffice your requirement then re-design your service such that client can initiate the long running process and then call another method on the service to query the status.

Comment: +1. To expound on the last point, `async` on the server side does not return *to the client* any sooner. The response is only sent to the client when the returned task completes.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Thanks. Yes, service side `async/await` asynchrony is not visible to the client.

Comment: Valuable question and good, clear answer. If the call is long running because the op at the service requires a lot of compute time I'm not sure I'd refer to it a resulting in a network timeout though. I imagine those relate to send/receive timeouts, whereas an operation timeout relates to those + compute time?

Comment: @TimBarrass: I'd used network timeout as generic term and not for any specific timeout. A WCF client operation may timeout due to high compute time on server as well as network latency.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must be sure that the problem is really the async call. Try call your service synchronously to see if the invoke happens with success.

Assuming that your problem is in fact the async operation, You should use the WCF `IAsyncResult`instead of `async`, since this is the default way of handling async operations in WCF. You will need an operation to begin the service, and another to process the results.

I could write some code, but here are some good posts that explain my point in details and are worth reading:

- [Building an Async WCF Service in .NET 4.5](http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2011/11/30/building-an-async-wcf-service-in-net-4-5/) (in this example, the `async` word comes before the WCF Service, and a Task is used to hold the operation inside the WCF invoke. It may be useful if you have more than one async invoke to the server)
- [How to: Implement an Asynchronous Service Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx)
- [Asynchronous Communication in a WCF Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121345/Asynchronous-Communication-in-a-WCF-Service)

> Another tip:
>
> After following these steps, if you realize that the client need more time to process the async
>   execution, consider to increase the `operation timeout` to allow a longer wait for the return. If the
>   connection is unstable, consider to increase the `open timeout` to
>   give more time to the client for establishing the connection.

Hope it helps.